# Link button in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I developed a web application, in that main page i used link buttons and write some code in link button click event, Problem is when i right click on the link buttons i am not finding open in new tab option in link buttons, how can i solve this problem can u help me please.

Comment: The linkbutton href is javascript so the browser can't just open it in a new window, it is a script that has to be run. If you explain why you want to do this then we might be able to help you.

Comment: @jarrett actually my client want this functionality. Is there any solution or alternative for this

Comment: If your link's location is calculated on the server side, you can add an HTML anchor tag such as `<a id="anchor" runat="server"></a>` and access it in the code behind as `HtmlAnchor`.  Then, you can set your calculated href on the server side.  Keep your current javascript in an onclick event, but at the end of the function, `return false;` so the click doesn't continue to the server.

Answer (score 0):

The [LinkButton control](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_linkbutton.asp) acts like a button.

Use [HyperLink control](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_hyperlink.asp) instead if you want to have the href behavior.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>


HyperLink1.Text = "Go to StackOverflow";
HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
```

Comment: This will work, but understand you lose the "click" event. As this renders as a regular anchor tag. @Surya - you can either have a LinkButton which has a click event and renders as "special" anchor tag (with an onclick), or you can have a Hyperlink which renders as a anchor tag with a href. You cannot have both a HREF and a server-side click (AFAIK).

Answer (score 0):

I think what @jarrett meant in his comment is that the resulting html that a LinkButton control generates is a `javascript:` href, not an href to a url - it's something along the lines of `javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$loginBtn", "", true, "", "", false, true))`

If you want the html output of a standard anchor tag/HyperLink (and the corresponding client browser behavior, including right-click to open in new tab or window) then use a standard anchor tag in your page `<a href="pageurlhere.com">Link to your page</a>`

If you need to be able to access the anchor tag from code-behind (assuming a Web Forms application) then you can add `runat="server"` to the tag and make it into a server-side Html Control, which is accessible to your code-behind.

Comment: @RPM1984 makes a good point regarding the click event, which I didn't consider, so my answer obviously may not satisfy your needs.